# Want to copy paste the program in python shell

Tags: python

I created a small program to calculate minutes in a week it executed well as I envisioned. but now I want to make little change in a program just to change the hours in a day from 24 to  26 so I just copy pasted the whole program in python shell itself and made a change as cited above and here is the problem :  It gives a syntax error:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: i added screen shot

Comment: You don't need to repeat all of the other lines to update one variable's value, just do `hourse_in_day=26` on its own then re-run the calculation for `minnutes_in_a_week`. But... that's not how many hours are in a day.

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is simply

```
>>>
```

is not supposed to be part of python syntax.

You have to remove them before you paste them.

```
>>> dayes_in_week = 7
>>> hourse_in_day = 24
>>> minutes_in_hour = 60
>>> minnutes_in_a_week = minutes_in_hour * hourse_in_day * dayes_in_week
>>> print(minnutes_in_a_week)
10080
>>> hourse_in_day = 26
>>> minnutes_in_a_week = minutes_in_hour * hourse_in_day * dayes_in_week
>>> print(minnutes_in_a_week)
10920
```

Comment: Are you sure that its not **shell itself** putting those symbols there?

Comment: The colors look different. Red/purplish color seems to be from the shell and black is user input.

Comment: Oh I guess youre right. That explains why the first trial did not give any syntax errors. He copied from shell to shell I guess.

Comment: @3yanlis1bos Yes